# TensorFlow Estimator API: use numpy functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have written several custom metrics which I would like to add to `tf.summary` and view in tensorboard via `metrics_op` in my `EstimatorSpec`.

Is it strictly required that I covert these functions to their tf graph equivalents to be compatible, or is there a way to just dump them in, e.g.

```
def model_fn(...):

    ...
    my_scalar_metric = my_np_func(output, labels)
    tf.summary.scalar('my_metric', my_scalar_metric)
    ...
```

Comment: You can try to wrap your function in `py_func`, but I am not sure that it will work